# Do we upgrade PHP or Drupal / Joomla! Core first?

Tags: php, drupal, joomla, drupal-7

Our Drupal 7/Joomla sites currently run on PHP 5.6 and require updates to both PHP and their core

What is the recommended sequence of update? PHP first or Drupal/Joomla!

Comment: Please ask Drupal questions on [drupal.se] and Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Use Docker containers to test your environnement under new php version ,and see what happen !

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it:
First make a list of extensions / modules that would need to be updated.  Then create a new server with PHP 7.2 and make a copy of the sites there. After that begin the process of updating step by step. First core, then modules and extensions. With each step solving possible problems that emerge.

Finally, when everything is working as expected, change the DNS to the new server.
This will give you the peace of mind that everything is running before going live.